# Inference the time a process would take depending on the number of threads

Tags: probability, average, statistical-inference

I have several datasets consisting on:

- Number of threads `n`
- Start process time `t1`
- Stop process time `t2`
- Operations processed `x`

So each line of the dataset mean `n` threads processed `x` operations in `t2-t1` time

When more threads are added, the processing time is reduced, because they run on parallel. However, they have locks between them, so the total time is not `(t2 -t1)/n`, but a bit more.

I would like to infer the time a process will take to do `x` operations depending on the thread number, some sort of "parallel factor" so `t = x * n * factor` gives me the estimated time. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Refer to Amdahl's law: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law